# How do I cope with "The TemplateBox was unable to use the specified display function..."?

Tags: stylesheet, logarithmic-scale, templates

$Version -> "12.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)"

I used

```
ListLogPlot[inzidenz, PlotRange -> {{-65, 11}, All}, 
 PlotLabel -> "RKI-Inzidenzzahlen, 0=6. Mai 2022", 
 AxesLabel -> {"Tage", "Inzidenz/100000"}]
```

and I got the desired plot, but the scaling is cluttered with errors:
[image: LogListPlot with y-axis cluttered with errors]

When mouse over, I see an error message

> "The TemplateBox was unable to use the specified display function, or
> it was unable to locate the display function possibly because a style
> sheet is missing."

```
• What does the message mean?

• How to cope with that?

• Were do I get the missing StyleSheet?
```

ListPlot called with the same parameters works as expected.

Trying to find out more, I fed the graphics to `FullForm`. I saw no error message there. Then I copied all the text as plain text and pasted it to a new Input cell:

```
Graphics[List[List[],List[List[List[Directive[PointSize[0.011000000000000001`],
RGBColor[0.368417`,0.506779`,0.709798`],
AbsoluteThickness[1.6`]],
Point[List[List[-60.`,7.625887712235991`],
List[-59.`,7.66692425508408`],List[-58.`,7.673455652223791`],
List[-57.`,7.689462636521562`],List[-56.`,7.72382780637938`],
List[-55.`,7.7533230722373085`],List[-54.`,7.773342016481586`],
List[-53.`,7.800695497248042`],List[-52.`,7.747467296623918`],
List[-51.`,7.703052828187015`],List[-50.`,7.707916607196564`],
List[-49.`,7.654490618712011`],List[-48.`,7.656005985768107`],
List[-47.`,7.668000203074577`],List[-46.`,7.6379091851711784`],
List[-45.`,7.605193240959238`],List[-44.`,7.536203925603146`],
List[-43.`,7.601252398306371`],List[-42.`,7.696712514388058`],
List[-41.`,7.654490618712011`],List[-40.`,7.549188023855404`],
List[-39.`,7.480879416942352`],List[-38.`,7.598198807967767`],
List[-37.`,7.630558344449593`],List[-36.`,7.591962617972608`],
List[-35.`,7.492314519125183`],List[-34.`,7.473693892801039`],
List[-33.`,7.473693892801039`],List[-32.`,7.473693892801039`],
List[-31.`,7.422732273870603`],List[-30.`,7.3771962499653965`],
List[-29.`,7.185689999979038`],List[-28.`,7.064929953354135`],
List[-27.`,7.015622649851144`],List[-26.`,7.015622649851144`],
List[-25.`,7.015622649851144`],List[-24.`,7.026693203053651`],
List[-23.`,7.0067858024450915`],List[-22.`,6.957687647730346`],
List[-21.`,6.919782659194856`],List[-20.`,6.769871571618751`],
List[-19.`,6.769871571618751`],List[-18.`,6.769871571618751`],
List[-17.`,6.259772650376566`],List[-16.`,6.57702651698799`],
List[-15.`,6.59468702013994`],List[-14.`,6.61056144615776`],
List[-13.`,6.760646413943925`],List[-12.`,6.760646413943925`],
List[-11.`,6.760646413943925`],List[-10.`,6.992280234051825`],
List[-9.`,6.719616836866618`],List[-8.`,6.697898071993661`],
List[-7.`,6.611099731731247`],List[-6.`,6.549221465558405`],
List[-5.`,6.549221465558405`],List[-4.`,6.549221465558405`],
List[-3.`,6.4446080905328875`],List[-2.`,6.466611178416954`],
List[-1.`,6.3690444517266105`],List[0.`,6.367500844525334`]]]]]],
List[List[],List[]]],
List[Rule[DisplayFunction,Identity],
Rule[GridLines,List[None,None]],Rule[DisplayFunction,Identity],
Rule[DisplayFunction,Identity],Rule[DisplayFunction,Identity],
Rule[DisplayFunction,Identity],Rule[AspectRatio,Power[GoldenRatio,-1]],
Rule[Axes,List[True,True]],Rule[AxesLabel,
List["Tage","Inzidenz/100000"]],
Rule[AxesOrigin,List[0,6.139186692825693`]],
RuleDelayed[DisplayFunction,Identity],
Rule[Frame,List[List[False,False],List[False,False]]],
Rule[FrameLabel,List[List[None,None],List[None,None]]],
Rule[FrameTicks,
List[List[Charting`ScaledTicks[List[Log,Exp]],
Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[List[Identity,Identity]]],
List[Automatic,Automatic]]],
Rule[GridLines,List[None,None]],
Rule[GridLinesStyle,Directive[GrayLevel[0.5`,0.4`]]],
Rule[Method,List[Rule["OptimizePlotMarkers",True],
Rule["OptimizePlotMarkers",True],
Rule["CoordinatesToolOptions",
List[Rule["DisplayFunction",
Function[List[Identity[Part[Slot[1],1]],Exp[Part[Slot[1],2]]]]],
Rule["CopiedValueFunction",
Function[List[Identity[Part[Slot[1],1]],Exp[Part[Slot[1],2]]]]]]]]],
Rule[PlotLabel,"RKI-Inzidenzzahlen, 0=6. Mai 2022"],
Rule[PlotRange,
List[List[-65,11],List[6.139186692825693`,7.800695497248042`]]],
Rule[PlotRangeClipping,True],
Rule[PlotRangePadding,List[List[0,0],
List[Scaled[0.02`],Scaled[0.05`]]]],
Rule[Ticks,List[Automatic,Charting`ScaledTicks[List[Log,Exp]]]]]]
```

Now I recognized that `'Charting'ScaledTicks` and `'Charting'ScaledFrameTicks` are printed in blue from which I conclude that the context `Charting` is missing.
Probably the error message about a StyleSheet is misleading! Now it looks to me that a package `Charting` is missing.

- **But where do I get it?**

Comment: There doesn't seem to be enough information in the post currently to replicate this error.

Comment: What additional Information do you need?
$Version -> "12.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (May 10, 2021)"

Comment: I would like to use your data to replicate the same plot/error on my setup. Do you get this error when you run `ListLogPlot` examples from the documentation as well?

Comment: "`Were do I get the missing StyleSheet?`" -- If you know this is the problem, what style sheet is missing?

Comment: Is the problem with `Ticks`? If so, what did you do wrong?

Comment: I edited my question to show some data and how ListLogPlot was called. - It looks like being a problem putting the numbers to the ticks: Thy are present in the graphics and it looks like a log scaled y-axis.

Comment: Michael E2: Now I understand your question: There must be some connection with ticks. See my post after editing.

Comment: Here are the [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3ZCT.png) on my setup. I copied the list values and plotted (left) and used the FullForm data you posted to the right (Charting is still in blue) but I cannot replicate the error on v12.2.0 Win7x64.

Comment: What does `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], StyleDefinitions]` return? Your problem is that the TemplateBox style for "Spacer2" is missing. Since this is part of the "Core" stylesheet, it can't go missing unless you changed the "Core" stylesheet, or you actually included a different definition for "Spacer2" in your stylesheet.

Comment: Carl, the output of `FrontEnd`FileName[{$RootDirectory, "home", "adalbert", 
  "Ahonote"}, "myDefault.nb", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]` is `FrontEnd`FileName[{$RootDirectory, "home", "adalbert", 
  "Ahonote"}, "myDefault.nb", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF-8"]`. I had modified the styles for Input, Output and Print to use Courier font, for Input in bold. Also there are some styles for text paragraphs with hanging indentation.

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen You need to include @ in front of my name if you want me to see your comment. One of your changes in `myDefault.nb` has disabled "Spacer2" formatting. You can either include `myDefault.nb` in your OP, or you can experiment with commenting out your various changes to see which one causes your issue.

Comment: @Carl Woll, how am I supposed to include myDefault.nb? Its size is 26kB and this would exceed the limit for the body of the OP.

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen If it's too big to include, then I don't see how I can help. You've done something in your style sheet that breaks the "Spacer2" style. With the default stylesheet, `RawBoxes@TemplateBox[{0, 0}, "Spacer2"]` displays as a basically invisible space. With your stylesheet, it looks like `Spacer2[0, 0]` with a pink background. Somewhere in your stylesheet, you eliminate the "Spacer2" style.

Comment: Now I have rest Mathematica to its default - the error still remained!

Comment: Then I have uninstalled Mathematica 12.3  following this recipe: https://support.wolfram.com/12473?src=mathematica. Then I installed Mathematica again from the original sh-file. After this, I let the same notebook run again. But the same error still shows up. Which file in which directory should define the Spacer2-style? Why is it still missing after a fresh install?